# Generate hyperlink from query

Tags: database, google-docs

My query is not returning the literal cell value, but rather only the visual portion of it.

I've got a google spreadsheet with FirstSheet having my info and then with the use of a query on SecondSheet showing part of the information.

The first column of FirstSheet has a hyperlink for each row in column A such as:

```
=hyperlink("http://www.google.com/test","My Test")
```

SecondSheet has a query that pulls that column amongst others such as:

```
=query('FirstSheet'!A2:C;"select*",0)
```

The query result only returns the label of the hyperlink but not the link itself or the hyperlink formula. Meaning I see the same text on both sheets but on SecondSheet it's not a link. I hope this makes sense.

I've thought about different ways to accomplish this including some how creating a string from a query to give me what I want, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the query to B2, selected column A last, putting it into Col C, hid C. I'm then using C with a formula I created in col A and then just pasted that formula down to row 100.

```
=If (C2="","",hyperlink("http://www.google.com/"&C2,C2))
```

I would have liked this to be more elegant, but it's good enough for now.